# Timezones not working for calendar event

Tags: icalendar, vcalendar, rfc5545

I am having difficulties with timezones in an event. This is the contents of the event, and it's specifying the event with a TZID. I am being told however that when people in Central timezone add it, it appears as 2PM rather then intended 1PM. I am in ET so not able to test this.

Do you know why it would be happening?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//http://XXX//Event
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID="America/Chicago":20150811T130000
DTEND;TZID="America/Chicago":20150811T141500
SUMMARY:Test Event
DESCRIPTION:Test Event
LOCATION:Test Event Location
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

See RFC5545, [Time Zone Component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5) and [Time Zone Identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.3.1): you need to add a `VTIMEZONE` component to your calendar file where you definea `TZID` so that you can refer to it in your `VEVENT`.

> ### Parameter Name:  [TZID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5)

> This parameter MUST be specified on the "DTSTART",
> "DTEND", "DUE", "EXDATE", and "RDATE" properties when either a
> DATE-TIME or TIME value type is specified and when the value is
> neither a UTC or a "floating" time. ***Failure to include and follow VTIMEZONE definitions in iCalendar objects may lead to inconsistent understanding of the local time
> at any given location.***

It should be noted that while Outlook/Exchange have repeatedly been reported to not require the `VTIMEZONE`, failure to include a `VTIMEZONE` leads to unpredictable behaviour from other calendars.